# Need help to create specific path in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I have no idea, How create this path in `xaml` (Windows Store App).

[image]

May be someone knows? 
Note: I can use only `xaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine three [arc segments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.arcsegment.aspx) like this:

```
<Path Stroke="DarkGreen" StrokeThickness="2"
 Data="M 50,0 A 100,100 0 0 0 0,86.6 A 100,100 0 0 0 100,86.6 A 100,100 0 0 0 50,0 Z"/>
```

The above path places three circle segment of radius 100 at the three corners of an equilateral triangle of side length 100. The height of that triangle is 86.6.

A more verbose way of writing the above path would be this:

```
<Path Stroke="DarkGreen" StrokeThickness="2">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="50,0" IsClosed="True">
                <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="0,86.6"/>
                <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="100,86.6"/>
                <ArcSegment Size="100,100" Point="50,0"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```